# elasticsearch undefined index and how to get rid of it

Tags: elasticsearch

I am seeing the following index Unassigned which is very annoying. How do I get rid of it

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Those unassigned shards are actually **unassigned replicas** of your actual shards from the *master node*.

The main purpose of replicas is for **failover**: if the node holding a primary shard dies, then a replica is promoted to the role of primary.

At index time, a replica shard does the same amount of work as the primary shard. New documents are first indexed on the primary and then on any replicas. Increasing the number of replicas does not change the capacity of the index.

However, replica shards can serve read requests. If, as is often the case, your index is search-heavy, you can increase search performance by increasing the number of replicas, but only if you also add extra hardware.

In order **to assign these shards**, you need to run a new instance of elasticsearch to create a *secondary node* **to carry the data replicas**. (The node can be *master eligible* or just a *workhorse*. Of course, you can set those configurations in the elasticsearch config files)

For more details about it you can refer to the [official documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/) and the [Elasticsearch Definitive Guide](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/index.html) (the work on it is still in progress but you will find what you are looking for [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_important_configuration_changes.html))